# How to run code on current row only

Tags: vba, excel

I have taken code from: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?25423-Solved-Excel-generate-calendar-appointments-in-Outlook (last post).

I do not want to run the code for rows 2 to 10. I want it to run on the row with the currently selected cell (i.e. if I am on cell J:19, then I only want it to run on row 19).

(The code opens a calendar appointment in Outlook based on data in certain cells.)

```
Option Explicit      

Sub AddToOutlook()       

    Dim OL As Outlook.Application 
    Dim olAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem 
    Dim NS As Outlook.Namespace 
    Dim colItems As Outlook.Items 
    Dim olApptSearch As Outlook.AppointmentItem 
    Dim r As Long, sSubject As String, sBody As String, sLocation As String 
    Dim dStartTime As Date, dEndTIme As Double, dReminder As Double, dCatagory As Double 
    Dim sSearch As String, bOLOpen As Boolean 

    On Error Resume Next 
    Set OL = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application") 
    bOLOpen = True 
    If OL Is Nothing Then 
        Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
        bOLOpen = False 
    End If 
    Set NS = OL.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
    Set colItems = NS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items 

    For r = 2 To 10    

        If Len(Sheet1.Cells(r, 2).Value & Sheet1.Cells(r, 1).Value) = 0 Then GoTo NextRow 
        sSubject = Sheet1.Cells(r, 2).Value 
        sBody = Sheet1.Cells(r, 5).Value 
        dStartTime = Sheet1.Cells(r, 1).Value 
        dEndTIme = Sheet1.Cells(r, 4).Value 
        sLocation = Sheet1.Cells(r, 6).Value 
        dReminder = 120 

        sSearch = "[Subject] = " & sQuote(sSubject) 
        Set olApptSearch = colItems.Find(sSearch) 

        If olApptSearch Is Nothing Then 
            Set olAppt = OL.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem) 
            olAppt.Body = sBody 
            olAppt.Subject = sSubject 
            olAppt.Start = dStartTime 
            olAppt.Duration = dEndTIme 
            olAppt.Location = sLocation 
            olAppt.Catagory = dCatagory 
            olAppt.Close olSave 
        End If 

NextRow: 
    Next r 

    If bOLOpen = False Then OL.Quit 

End Sub


Function sQuote(sTextToQuote) 
    sQuote = Chr(34) & sTextToQuote & Chr(34) 
End Function
```

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` (when used the way you are using it) is a bad idea. You are hiding any errors which your code might raise. Sweeping a problem under the rug doesn't solve it

Comment: All comments seem very good and look to solve the problem - I will report back tomorrow once at the computer again. Many thanks. John Coleman I see your point but and will see if any errors occur if I take that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to remove the `For...Next` statement.

As gunfulker stated in his answer, you will also need to make `r` a static value, and because you want this to be whichever cell is selected at the time you would use `r = ActiveCell.Row`.

Some more info on [range.row](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-row-property-excel):

> Returns the number of the first row of the first area in the range. Read-only **Long** .
>
> **Syntax**
>
> *expression* . **Row**
>
> *expression* A variable that represents a **Range** object.

So this code should work for you:

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddToOutlook()
    
    Dim OL As Outlook.Application
    Dim olAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim NS As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim colItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim olApptSearch As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim r As Long, sSubject As String, sBody As String, sLocation As String
    Dim dStartTime As Date, dEndTIme As Double, dReminder As Double, dCatagory As Double
    Dim sSearch As String, bOLOpen As Boolean
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set OL = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    bOLOpen = True
    If OL Is Nothing Then
        Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        bOLOpen = False
    End If
    Set NS = OL.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set colItems = NS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items
    
    r = ActiveCell.row
        
    If Len(Sheet1.Cells(r, 2).Value & Sheet1.Cells(r, 1).Value) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    sSubject = Sheet1.Cells(r, 2).Value
    sBody = Sheet1.Cells(r, 5).Value
    dStartTime = Sheet1.Cells(r, 1).Value
    dEndTIme = Sheet1.Cells(r, 4).Value
    sLocation = Sheet1.Cells(r, 6).Value
    dReminder = 120

    sSearch = "[Subject] = " & sQuote(sSubject)
    Set olApptSearch = colItems.Find(sSearch)


    If olApptSearch Is Nothing Then
        Set olAppt = OL.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
        olAppt.body = sBody
        olAppt.Subject = sSubject
        olAppt.Start = dStartTime
        olAppt.Duration = dEndTIme
        olAppt.Location = sLocation
        olAppt.Catagory = dCatagory
        olAppt.Close olSave
    End If

    If bOLOpen = False Then OL.Quit

End Sub


Function sQuote(sTextToQuote)
    sQuote = Chr(34) & sTextToQuote & Chr(34)
End Function
```

Comment: Change the "Dim r as Long" to "as Range". Also the "GoTo NextRow" should be change to "Exit Sub"

Comment: @GMalc59 but it’s not a range object. It’s intended for use within `Cells()`. `.row` returns a ‘Long’ data type. Look at the highlighted portion of my answer: “_read-only **Long**_”.

Comment: And I didn’t even notice the `GoTo` statement when I copied the original code. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @K.Davis your right, i over looked the .row, its easy when focusing on something and then miss the good stuff.

Answer (score 2):

```
For r = 2 To 10
```

becomes

```
For r = ActiveCell.Row To ActiveCell.Row
```

for the fastest fix. In other words, only do it for the active row, not 2 through 10

The correct way of doing it would be to replace that line with

```
r = ActiveCell.Row
```

unindent the code block up to the `Next r` statement, and remove the `Next r` statement.

Someone who knows VBA better can give you a more reliable answer.